# Using a different math font for a single character

Tags: fonts, latex, pdflatex

I'm currently writing a math-heavy document in latex and I use the new century schoolbook font for the text and a matching math font, millennial, for the math. Millennial can be found here: https://www.math.unl.edu/~shartke2/computer/latex/latex.php

My problem is that millennial seems to somehow break the \dagger symbol; it simply doesn't show on the document and it doesn't seem to use any space. I really like the appearance of millennial and I'd like to keep it, but I also absolutely need the dagger symbol.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{millennial}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        a^{\dagger}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to know how to use another math font just for that symbol, or any other way to solve my problem.

I'm using pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013).

Thank you!

Comment: Follow the guidelines presented in [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Werner but I couldn't find the code for the dagger (as \cup was "80 in the example).

I fixed my issue by adding \renewcommand{\dagger}{\text{\textdagger}} in my preamble.